# Create an Ektron catalog and Product Types programatically

Tags: asp.net, ektron

I have a series of sites and need to update them all with a simple catalog and 3 basic product types in that catalog.  Is there a way to create the product types programatically (just a name and type specified) and then create a catalog with those 3 types in it?

I am using 8.0.1 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

While you may be slightly better off just creating the product type once in your first instance and then copying the package to your additional servers to save time, the jist of doing this via code is as follows:

```
    //Put user code to initialize the page here
    Ektron.Cms.Commerce.ProductTypeApi ptapi = new Ektron.Cms.Commerce.ProductTypeApi();
    Ektron.Cms.Commerce.ProductTypeData ptdata = new Ektron.Cms.Commerce.ProductTypeData();
    ptdata.Title = "Title of Product Type";
    //Define additional attributes and properties to your new product type below
    //ptdata.
    ptapi.Add(ptdata);

    //Now that your product type is created assign it to a folder (Automatically giving admin access to create)
    Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization.FolderManager fmanager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization.FolderManager(Ektron.Cms.Framework.ApiAccessMode.Admin);
    Ektron.Cms.FolderData fdata = new Ektron.Cms.FolderData();
    Ektron.Cms.Content.EkContent ekcontent = new Ektron.Cms.Content.EkContent();

    long idofproducttype = 5;

    Ektron.Cms.XmlConfigData xmlconfig = ekcontent.GetXmlConfigurationData(idofproducttype);
    fdata.Name = "Catalog Name";
    fdata.Type = Ektron.Cms.Common.EkEnumeration.FolderType.Catalog;
    fdata.XmlConfiguration[0] = xmlconfig;
    fmanager.Add(fdata);
```

Comment: I am getting "Input string was not in a correct format." message when trying to create the product type.  Others have apparently had this problem also.  http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=32006 see Tanyas comment.